# Best way to iterate over S3 and download each file separately into python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a large amount of files in S3 (~150gb of text files) in a fairly simple folder structure. There are a number of folders and within each of these there are several Gb of files. I would like to use boto3 to iterate over the contents of s3 and download each file, operate on that file in python (does not need to reupload/alter the original in s3) and then move on to the next file. The hard part is there are also other objects in the bucket that I would like to ignore, such as some of the folders and zip files that are present.

I've had some luck with the following to list the contents of s3, but I don't know how to access the names of the files within python

```
for object in s3.Bucket('name_of_bucket').objects.all():
    print(object)
```

printing the object gives the name of the files, but I don't know how to access the contents of the object within python. The object is a `boto3.resources.factory.s3.ObjectSummary` object.

I'm either looking for help with how to use this method or a completely different method.

Thank you in advance

Comment: s3.download_object(object.fpath) or something anlong those lines

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't address the question above

Comment: Have you considered [S3 batch](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/batch-operations/). Seems as a good match for your usage case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like `print(object)`, you can check the name of the object via `object.key` and, if desired, download it with `object.download_file`.

You can then access the contents of the file on the local disk.

While you could use `object.get()` and then access the contents via the streaming body `Body` response, it is better to read/manipulate the file from the local disk.

All functions are documented in: [Boto3 Docs: S3 Object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object)

Answer (score 1):

use download_file method

```
for obj in first_bucket.objects.all():
     subsrc = obj.Object()
     print(obj.key)  # gives file name
     obj.download_file(f'/tmp/{obj.key}')   # download file
```